# Android - Fetching string data from sqlite and change listview input with if condition

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, cursor

I am fetching data from sqlite and displaying in a list view.  All the data in sqlite is stored as `String`.  For example,

```
ImageName   UploadStatus
test1.jpg       1
test2.jpg       2
```

I am using cursor to fetch the data as follows:

```
cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * from activityRes", null);
        ImageName_Array.clear();
        UploadStatus_Array.clear();
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    ImageName_Array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ImageName"))); 
                    UploadStatus_Array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("UploadStatus")));
//                    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("UploadStatus")) == "1") {
//                        UploadStatus_Array.add("Y");
//                    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("UploadStatus")) == "2") {
//                        UploadStatus_Array.add("N");
//                    }
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
```

The UploadStatus_Array.add gets me the data and displays it as 1 and 2.  However, I want to change the display as `Y` and `N`.  I tried with the commented codes...but it is throwing the entire table out.

Comment: why don't you just remove UploadStatus_Array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("UploadStatus"))); ?

Comment: I have removed it...when running the other part of the code

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem? When you remove it, you'll simply add either Y or N depending on the value whether it's 1 or 2 respectively

Comment: I am able to render it as 1 and 2.  However, if I comment out the UploadStatus.Array line and uncomment the subsequent 5 lines,to convert 1to Y and 2 to N, it is not working

Comment: Well... please log the value of cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("UploadStatus")) and see what is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to execute a query that will return the results as you want them and just add them to the lists.
All you have to do is use a `CASE` expression in the `SELECT` statement and you will have the column `UploadStatus` populated with `Y`s and `N`s:

```
String sql = "SELECT ImageName, CASE UploadStatus WHEN '1' THEN 'Y' WHEN '2' THEN 'N' END AS UploadStatus FROM activityRes"
cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
ImageName_Array.clear();
UploadStatus_Array.clear();
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    ImageName_Array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ImageName"))); 
    UploadStatus_Array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("UploadStatus")));
}
```

There is no need to check if `cursor` is `null`. The result of `rawQuery()` is never `null`.
Also there is no need to check if `cursor.getCount()` is greater than `0` because `while (cursor.moveToNext())` is enough.

Comment: thank you...your solution worked...also allowed me to think differently about the sql queries